# Show a specific taxonomy (Category) in a page template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called Short Courses and I have added a custom taxonomy to to it called Course Types, which enables me to categorise the courses...

Im trying to create a page template that will show all courses with a single taxonomy (category). In this case I Want to show all courses that have been assigned the taxonomy (category) Adobe... Ive tried a few different things, but heres my latest code:

```
<?php 

// get the custom post type's taxonomy terms

$custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'adobe', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'short_courses',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 20, // you may edit this number
'orderby' => 'rand',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'adobe',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $custom_taxterms
    )
),
'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
);
$related_items = new WP_Query( $args );

// loop over query
if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

It doesn't pull through anything...

I have tried with this code too:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'short_courses',
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'product_categories' => 'adobe'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


      <?php
        $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
        $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
      ?>

      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic"></a></p>
      <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>     


  <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
  <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

  <?php endif; ?>


  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But this code pulls through ALL of the short courses, not just the Adobe ones...

Can anyone tel me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix this - it was just a little mistake. In the second lot of code above, the part that says product_categories needed changing to course_type! So heres the new working code:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'short_courses',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'course_type' => 'adobe'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

     ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


          <?php
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
            $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
          ?>

          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic"></a></p>
          <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>     


      <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed this line?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while
```

Can you change it to

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while
```

and see if the filter is applied? WordPress has global post functions such such **get_the_title()** and this may interfere with your custom query objects such as the one you are using **$the_query**.

I would also advise you to remove the **if** statement before the while to improve readability of the code. The while loop will not produce any output on the page if the query doesn't have any posts anyways so need of the if statement.

The entire code then becomes

```
<?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'short_courses',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'product_categories' => 'adobe'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

      <?php  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


          <?php
            $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
            $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
          ?>

          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic"></a></p>
          <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>     


      <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Please make sure that the taxonomy name you are using on **'product_categories' => 'adobe'** is the same one you used on the **register_taxonomy** function i.e.  Ensure that you have **register_taxonomy('product_categories', array('short_courses'), $args );** If you have anything else on **product_categories**, then use that on the query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have ay effect I'm afraid @Nkole - I've updated my code with this addition...